# NOT IN not working sufficient

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I wrote this to get me the patients who have never had the diagnosis codes stated. But I am getting results of people who DID. Only that it's NOT displaying that codes in the output but other codes they have.
But I need to not include the patient who has that code but the NOT IN part
is not working or what else am I missing?

```
  select Distinct a.voucher_primary_diagnosis_code, a.Patient_Number, b.Patient_Name vwGenVouchInfo a 
    left join vwGenPatInfo b on a.Patient_Number=b.patient_number
    where
    a.Department_Descr = 'Pediatrics' and Actual_Dr_ID <> 6 and Voucher_Primary_Diagnosis_Code not in 
    ('Z00.129', 'Z00.00') order by patient_name
```

Comment: have you tried inner join?

Comment: you are also missing "FROM"

Comment: inner join the other way you mean? good idea let me see.

Comment: i have from there no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NOT IN` condition applies to a single row. However, you are looking for *non-existence* of any rows associated with the given patient that match the specified codes, so you need a different condition: you need to say that for a given patient there's no diagnosis code on the specified list. For example, you could use `EXISTS` quantifier for that:

```
SELECT
    a.voucher_primary_diagnosis_code
,   a.Patient_Number
,   b.Patient_Name
FROM vwGenVouchInfo a 
LEFT JOIN vwGenPatInfo b ON a.Patient_Number=b.Patient_Number
WHERE
    a.Department_Descr = 'Pediatrics'
AND Actual_Dr_ID <> 6
AND NOT EXISTS (
    -- This subquery looks at other vouchers of the same patient.
    -- If any of them has Diagnosis Code from the prohibited list,
    -- all records for that patient are rejected.
    SELECT *
    FROM vwGenVouchInfo v
    WHERE v.Patient_Number=b.Patient_Number
      AND v.Voucher_Primary_Diagnosis_Code IN ('Z00.129', 'Z00.00')
)
ORDER BY Patient_Name
```

Comment: Thank you both for sharing your wealth of knowledge with me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `left join`.  Here is one way to get the *patients* who meet your description:

```
select p.Patient_Number, p.Patient_Name
from vwGenPatInfo p left join
     vwGenVouchInfo v
     on p.Patient_Number = v.patient_number and
        v.Department_Descr = 'Pediatrics' and
        v.Actual_Dr_ID <> 6 and
        v.Voucher_Primary_Diagnosis_Code in ('Z00.129', 'Z00.00')
where v.patient_number is null
order by p.patient_n
```

Note this doesn't return information about diagnoses, because you are getting the patients who don't have the diagnoses you care about.